# Scala Regex with $ and String Interpolation

Tags: scala

I am writing a regex in scala

```
val regex = "^foo.*$".r
```

this is great but if I want to do

```
var x = "foo"
val regex = s"""^$x.*$""".r
```

now we have a problem because $ is ambiguous. is it possible to have string interpolation and be able to write a regex as well?

I can do something like

```
val x = "foo"
val regex = ("^" + x + ".*$").r
```

but I don't like to do a `+`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `$$` to have a literal `$` in an interpolated string.

You should use the `raw` interpolator when enclosing a string in triple-quotes as the `s` interpolator will re-enable escape sequences that you might expect to be interpreted literally in triple-quotes.  It doesn't make a difference in your specific case but it's good to keep in mind.

so `val regex = raw"""^$x.*$$""".r`

Answer (score 3):

Using `%s` should work.

```
var x = "foo"
val regex = """^%s.*$""".format(x).r
```

In the off case you need `%s` to be a regex match term, just do

```
val regex = """^%s.*%s$""".format(x, "%s").r
```